# Streaming data over USB in python / mimic usb drive with python?

Tags: python, streaming, usb, emulation

I would like to know if the following is possible:
I want to connect my computer to either another computer, or a some consumer electronics (like a ps3 or xbox or something), via a double sided USB cable. I want to run a program on the first computer that will run a constant data stream through the USB cable, to trick the second computer into believing it is a usb flash drive, and it can read data from it. The first computer can change the data stream accordingly to the files that are supposed to be on the emulated flash drive.

Essentially, I want to use a program on a computer to mimic USB hardware in another device.

I don't know if I am wording this is a proper way or not, but is this possible?

Diagram:

| My Computer running this program | >-----emulated USB data stream-----> | Target |

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without special hardware because USB doesn't support peer-to-peer networks. You might do better with Firewire (IEEE-1394), which can at least be used for TCP/IP with appropriate drivers.

Comment: what if it went from a serial port on my computer to the USB port on another computer? could I make a program on my computer to make the connection appear like a flash or usb drive?

Comment: Sure. You'd want something other than Python though, and you'd need special software on the computer that sees the "drive."

Comment: Ah. Well alas, that is where the problem lies, as I wouldn't be able to install software on the other computer. I'll  be looking into a hardware solution for what I am trying to accomplish.  [this](http://hackaday.com/2012/07/05/facedancer-board-lets-your-python-programs-pretend-to-be-usb-hardware/) and [this](http://travisgoodspeed.blogspot.com/2012/07/emulating-usb-devices-with-python.html) are essentially what I want, but without the hardware...